# How to pass a custom data of class to window callback without declaring it as static?

Tags: c++, winapi, capture

I have a class "Camera" that uses vfw32 capture API. According to APi I can set a callback function of capture procedure by calling `capSetCallbackOnFrame`. I defined a `OnCapture` callback as a lambda:

```
OnCapture = [](HWND CWH, LPVIDEOHDR VHDR)->int{/*...code...*/}
```

There is no place in callback declaration for user_data, except LPVIDEOHDR's dwUser, but I don't know how to modify it before call.

How to use the class's members inside this callback without declaring it as static (and callback itself without static)?

Comment: Most Win32 callback APIs allow custom data in a callback. This is an exception, but VfW is way hell old (Win 95). Use Media Foundation.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, thanks, nice... Have any examples of camera capture with Media Foundation?

Comment: You can try using std::invoke which can take a member function and the compiler will do its magic ^_^

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/audio-video-capture-in-media-foundation

Comment: Is being non-static super important? Or to put it another way, do you want a working solution or are you more interested in fancy C++ tricks?